# Keep first 100 lines in a text file and delete the remainder

Tags: python

I am rather new to Python (Python 3) and have managed to write several scripts to perform various checks and functions.  Each script writes information to a text file that is used as a log file (myLogFile.txt) and the newest information is at the beginning (top) of the file.  The log files are getting to be rather large and I would like to purge the older information at the end of the file but am not sure how to accomplish the task with Python.  I have searched on how to do it but everything I've found reads and prints the first N lines.

What I would like to do is read the file and purge everything after, say 100 lines.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: Using the examples that read and print the first N lines, you can simply replace the whole text file with those first N lines.

Comment: Use `file.readlines()[0:100]` to read the first 100 lines into a list. Then overwrite the file with the contents of that list.

Comment: Wouldn't the older information be at the **beginning** of the file? In which case you would probably want to keep the **last** 100 lines…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job :)

```
N = 100 # number of lines you want to keep
with open("myLogFile.txt","r+") as f:
   data = f.readlines()
   if len(data) > N: data = data[0:N]
   f.seek(0)
   f.writelines(data)
   f.truncate()
```

Comment: This one worked without much screaming and yelling!

Comment: @Kevin you are welcome dude

Answer (score 0):

Read only 100 lines, then write them back, that's th easiest

```
with open("my_file.txt") as fic:
    lines = [fic.readline() for _ in range(100)]

with open("my_file.txt", 'w') as fic:
    fic.writelines(lines)
```